# Gstreamer stream and record video on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, video-capture

I am working on the following pipeline:

```
raspivid -t 0 -h 1080 -w 1920 -fps 24 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v 
-e fdsrc ! tee name=t t. ! h264parse ! queue ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 
pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.81 port=5600 t. ! queue ! * I NEED HELP HERE * 
! filesink location=/home/pi/myvid.mp4
```

I have tried inserting many things into the * I NEED HELP HERE * section, but nothing has worked. All I am trying to do is record a video while also streaming it.

Inserting the following does not work (separate lines for separate insertions):

```
1) h264parse ! mp4mux

2) videoparse ! avimux

3) video/x-h264,width=1920,hieght=1080,framerate=24/1 ! avimux
```

1) Buffer has no PTS

2) Can't remember what was wrong with this one, don't think it is valid

3) Spits out a bunch of inability to parse errors or something similar

I've been trying just about everything I can find on google and keep getting obscure error after obscure error.

Comment: 1) sounds about right. weird that no timestamps are found though. maybe the h264 stream does not have any or h264parse does not fill in the fields in the GstBuffer. Perhaps try `do-timestamp=true` for the `fdsrc`.

Comment: could you post the output of the following command: raspivid -t 0 -h 1080 -w 1920 -fps 24 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -v -e fdsrc ! h264parse ! identity silent=false ! queue ! tee name=t t. !  queue ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.81 port=5600 t. ! queue ! mp4mux !  filesink location=/home/pi/myvid.mp4